# Facing problem to use inject method of koin in java android

Tags: koin, koin-scope, android-koin

I ma trying to use koin dependency injection.
Implemented successfully but the problem is I am unable to reach Inject method as activity show error in that word.  val favTemplateDao by inject()

what am I missing everything implemented as it has to be like dependencies, koin is Started in base class. but still unable to reach inject methd.

what am I missing??

implemented every thing.